# I tried to create AJAX function but it shows noting in output

Tags: javascript, ajax

I tried to create AJAX function but it shows noting in output

```js
var ajaxObj = function(url, meth, data = "") {
                var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
                x.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
                        this.responseAjax = this.responseText;
                    }
                }
                x.open(meth, url, true);
                x.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                x.send(data);
    
            }
    
            function showHint(str) {
                var xhttp = new ajaxObj("gethint.php?q=" + str, "GET");
                if (str.length == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                }
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xhttp.responseAjax;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <body>
    
        <h3> Start typing a name in the input field below :</h3>
    
        <form action="">
            First Name : <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
    </form>
    
        <p>Suggestions:
            <sapn id="txtHint"></sapn>
        </p>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

I tried to get suggested Names from gethint.php file when user starts typing into text box.
But it seems that responseAjax gets value after showHint() call please help me.

Comment: Does showHint() actually pull something? Or is the response empty?

Comment: It worked with inline ajax code

Comment: It request data from gethint.php file

Comment: because you are making the Ajax call totally wrong unless your `ajaxObj` is synchronous. Not knowing what ajaxObj is, it is really hard to help.

Comment: Then please show me how to correct it

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside `onreadystatechange`'s handler is an instance of `XMLHttpRequest` so the line `this.responseAjax = this.responseText` is adding a field to the `XMLHttpRequest` object and setting its value to another field in the same object. This is completely redundant. In `showHint`, `xhttp` is an instance of `ajaxObj` and there is no `responseAjax` field ever defined for this object. You can directly set `innerHTML` of the element that shows suggestion inside the handler of `onreadystatechange` like the following:

```
function getSuggestions (meth, data) {
    meth = meth.toUpperCase();
    var params = "q=" + data;
    var url = (meth == "GET") ? "gethint.php?" + params : "gethint.php";

    var elem = document.getElementById("txtHint");

    if (data.length == 0) {
        elem.innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }

    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();

    x.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
            elem.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    }
    x.open(meth, url, true);
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    if (meth == "GET") { 
        x.send(); 
    } else { 
        x.send(params); 
    }

}
```

and `showHint` becomes:

```
function showHint(str) {
    getSuggestions ("GET", str);
}
```

Comment: I want to use above code in all condition, not just for extending innerHTML or just to GET method. I want to replace all those ajax lines by just one single function or object.      
But thank you your answer give me some hint for what I should do next.

Comment: "I want to use above code in all condition, not just for extending innerHTML" if you want to handle the  response in a certain way, you can invoke a method when the response arrives. See Danny's answer below. If you just want to change HTTP method for this request, you simply invoke `getSuggestions` like this: `getSuggestions (/*your method*/"POST", str);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the AJAX request asynchronously. In your `showHint` function when you call

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xhttp.responseAjax;
```

the AJAX call has not yet returned, so the xhttp.responseAjax object is not yet defined. You need to wait to handle the response once it arrives. You can pass a callback function in to the `ajaxObj` definition, and the object will call that function when it gets its response.

```
var ajaxObj = function(url, meth, callback, data = "") {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {

            // we're ready to handle the response data now
            callback(x.responseText);
        }
    }
    x.open(meth, url, true);
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    x.send(data);

}

// Callback function to be invoked when AJAX is complete
function fillTxtHint(responseHtml)
{
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = responseHtml;
}

function showHint(str) {

    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    }

    // Pass in the callback function to be invoked when AJAX has returned
    ajaxObj("gethint.php?q=" + str, "GET", fillTxtHint);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot, but problem is that xhttp's scope in fillTxtHint method. I'll figure it out by my self. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: A small correction, `if (str.length == 0) {...` should come before `var xhttp = ....` in `showHint`

Comment: With the timing of the ajax call, the `#txtHint` clearing is going to happen pretty quickly either way, but I did move it ahead. it's also simpler to just call the `ajaxObj` function directly. I hadn't updated the `fillTxtHint` method to use the local variable name (was still using the xhttp field), but that should be good now.